# howto append/modify files in docker container from 'docker run .... [command]'

Tags: shell, docker, redis

I want to modify conf files in a docker image, however, I don't want to re-build the docker image, instead, **I want to do this thru the "docker run .... COMMAND"**. I will put an "echo XXX >> /etc/XXX.conf" into the COMMAND. is this possible?

for example, I want to start a redis sentinel cluster, which includes at least 2 redis-server and 1 redis-sentinel. The second redis-server container need state "slaveof" in the redis.conf.

I do this in the following steps:

1. start redis-server with port 6479

   `docker run -d -p 6479:6379 docker.io/redis`
2. start slave redis-server with 6579 by using same docker images, and state it's a slave in the conf file:

   `docker run -d -p 6579:6379 docker.io/redis "/bin/echo 'slaveof 192.168.1.149 6479' >> /etc/redis.conf && redis-server /etc/redis.conf"`

Here the COMMAND for 'docker run' is: 
"/bin/echo 'slaveof 192.168.1.149 6479' >> /etc/redis.conf && redis-server /etc/redis.conf"

3. Start sentinel, this is another docker images.

However, I stopped at the 2nd step. It returned error message like this:

> /entrypoint.sh: line 10: /bin/echo 'slaveof 192.168.1.149 6479' >>
>   /etc/redis.conf && redis-server /etc/redis.conf: No such file or
>   directory

So, how can I inject or modify conf file thru 'docker run' clause?

Answer (score 1):

First launch your container giving it some name which you will need later (its easier than looking up container-id)

```
docker run --name container-name -d -p 6479:6379 docker.io/redis
docker run --name aaaaa          -d -p 6479:6379 docker.io/redis
```

If you need to login to a running container issue

```
docker exec -ti aaaaa  /bin/bash
```

which will give you an interactive shell session inside the container where you can issue commands at will ... If you just want to issue a command inside a running container without the interactive aspect issue

```
docker exec -ti aaaaa /some/command
```

where that  /some/command will be executed inside the container ... so something like this in your case

```
docker exec -ti  aaaaa  "/bin/echo 'slaveof 192.168.1.149 6479' >> /etc/redis.conf && redis-server /etc/redis.conf"
```

Comment: Thanks Scott, this doesn't work for me. Btw, the docker aaaaa should use port 6579 :)

I checked your method by either of these 2 ways:

a) from the host, run "redis-cli -p 6579 info replication", it still says that this redis is master, but if everything works, it should be slave.

b) I login by "docker exec -ti aaaaaa /bin/bash", there is no /etc/redis.conf. This means the 'echo .....' doesn't work.


In the end, the "docker exec" clause should not work in my opinion, because the docker container has started and functional. "docker exec" will not affect existing redis server behavior.